# Sort Date in React Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am trying to sort the Date column. Currently the sort is alphabetical order. Below is my code for your perusal.

JSON

```
[
  {
    "date": "Jun-2022"
  },
  {
    "date": "Jul-2022"
  },
  {
    "date": "Nov-2022"
  }
]
```

```
 columns = [
                {
                    Header: 'MONTH',
                    accessor: 'date',
                    // sortType: (a:any, b:any) => {
                    //     return new Date(b.values.date) - new Date(a.values.date);
                        
                    // }
                },
```

Error Message is: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.ts(2362)

Answer (score 0):

When comparing date, always use the getTime() to have the time in number format.

```js
const dateTable = [{
    "date": "Jun-2022"
  },
  {
    "date": "Nov-2022"
  },
  {
    "date": "Jul-2022"
  },
]
console.log(dateTable.sort((a, b) => (new Date(a.date).getTime() < new Date(b.date).getTime() ? -1 : 1)))
```

Comment: The issue is 'Jun-2022' etc. are not valid dates, so this sort won't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert them into number format and invoke the sort with a callback function.

The official docs of the sort would be a great start, please see [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

My solution is below.

```js
const dateTable = [{
    "date": "Jun-2022"
  },
  {
    "date": "Nov-2022"
  },
  {
    "date": "Jul-2022"
  },
]

const numberFormat = (date) => {
  return new Date(date.date).getTime();
}

console.log(dateTable.sort((a, b) => numberFormat(a) - numberFormat(b)));
```

Comment: I've converted to a snippet and rearranged the dates. You'll see it doesn't sort correctly.

Comment: How is it not correctly sorted ?
Jun - Jul - Nov

Comment: Thanks for doing that, @KScandrett. It does sort correctly tbh.

Comment: It may be because of regional date formats (I'm dmy). For me the output is Jun, Nov, July

Comment: @jdel I see Jun, Nov, Jul in the console output

Comment: totally agree, it works fine with me.

Comment: @KScandrett when I use the snippet, it display Jun-Jul-Nov. And also in my console ...

Comment: @jdel, this is what I see for your answer https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoJKn.png

Comment: @Evan, https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PRpW.png.  When I `console.log(new Date(date.date).getTime());` in the `numberFormat` function it returns NaN

Comment: Where is the NaN in your screenshot?

Comment: I took the screenshot before I tried to work out why. 'Nov-22' is not a valid date, it's missing the day of the month

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbAl2.png

Comment: https://capture.dropbox.com/Jxyi4fy7Nm6dTScb It does work for me tbh. Ping me, if you want to discuss it, mate. https://twitter.com/teamevancodes